# Why does Firefox ignore margin auto to center items?

Tags: html, css, margin, responsive

I made a website with a countdown.

https://leagueseason.com

I used flipclockJS for the countdown and customized it to make it responsive.
I also used media queries for that. The countdown is responsive on every Browser except Firefox. It doesn't center my items anymore when you make your window smaller.

I could paste my CSS file here but it would be way too long. Instead I can tell you that I'm using the file main.css on my website for customizing my stuff.

Can you explain me why Firefox ignores my mx-auto and what I can do to center it?

Comment: Please see how to create an [mcve].  And keep in mind that half the point of creating an [mcve] is that you will likely discover the answer on your own in the process of trimming down to only the necessary css....

Comment: Note: after doing some fiddling, it has to do with the combination of `transform: scale` and `width: -moz-fit-content` ...

Answer (score -2):

I think you must use the prefix webkit-